# How can it be that a function is outputing a vector with 38 elements and Simulink takes it as one element?

Tags: matlab, simulink

In the Simulink model below my interpreted function output is a vector with 38 elements. I have two functions that have the same outputs one of them works perfectly (desiredtrajectory_sim.m) but the other one doesn't (desiredtrajectory.m).
Any suggestions. thanks

Here is the Simulink model[image: 1]

```
function [desired_state] = desiredtrajectory_sim(in)
t = in(1);
Sf = [ 1; 2; pi/4];
dSf = [0;0;0];

Pf = [ 0.1*t; 0; 0.5*sin(0.03*pi*t) + 2; 0; 0.01*pi*t ; 0];
dPf = [ 0.1; 0; 0.5*0.03*pi*cos(0.03*pi*t); 0; 0.01*pi; 0];

pf = Sf(1); qf = Sf(2); betaf = Sf(3);
xf = Pf(1); yf = Pf(2); zf = Pf(3);
phif = Pf(4); thetaf = Pf(5); psif = Pf(6);

rf  = sqrt(pf^2 + qf^2 - 2*pf*qf*cos(betaf));         
h1 =  sqrt(0.5*(pf^2 + qf^2 - 0.5*rf^2));
h2 =  sqrt(0.5*(rf^2 + pf^2 - 0.5*qf^2));
h3 =  sqrt(0.5*(qf^2 + rf^2 - 0.5*pf^2));                   
alpha1  = acos((4*(h1^2+h2^2)-9*pf^2)/(8*h1*h2));
alpha2  = acos((4*(h1^2+h3^2)-9*qf^2)/(8*h1*h3));
Rot = RPYtoRot_ZXY(phif, thetaf, psif);
r1 = Rot*[2/3*h1;0;0];
r2 = Rot*[2/3*h2*cos(alpha1);2/3*h2*sin(alpha1);0];
r3 = Rot*[2/3*h3*cos(alpha2);-2/3*h3*sin(alpha2);0];
pos_des1 = [xf;yf;zf] + r1;
pos_des2 = [xf;yf;zf] + r2;
pos_des3 = [xf;yf;zf] + r3;

omega = [0 -sin(psif) cos(thetaf)*cos(psif);...
     0 -cos(psif) cos(thetaf)*sin(psif);...
     1     0         -sin(thetaf)]*dPf(4:6);

vel_des1 =  dPf(1:3) + cross(omega, r1);
vel_des2 =  dPf(1:3) + cross(omega, r2);
vel_des3 =  dPf(1:3) + cross(omega, r3);
acc_des = [0;0;0];

desired_state1 = [pos_des1;vel_des1;acc_des];
desired_state2 = [pos_des2;vel_des2;acc_des];
desired_state3 = [pos_des3;vel_des3;acc_des];

desired_state = [desired_state1;desired_state2;desired_state3; psif; 0; Pf; 
Sf]
size(desired_state)
end
```

Here is the Simulink block and the error message[image: 2]
As you can notice the bus gives just one element compared to the previous one which gives 38 elements, although they have the same output.

```
function [desired_state] = desiredtrajectory(in)%(t, pos)
tm= in(1)
pos = in(2:10);
syms t xf yf zf phif thetaf psif pf qf betaf

rf  = sqrt(pf^2+qf^2-2*pf*qf*cos(betaf));

              h1 =  sqrt(0.5*(pf^2+qf^2-0.5*rf^2));
              h2 =  sqrt(0.5*(rf^2+pf^2-0.5*qf^2));
              h3 =  sqrt(0.5*(qf^2+rf^2-0.5*pf^2));

alf1  = acos((4*(h1^2+h2^2)-9*pf^2)/(8*h1*h2));
alf2  = acos((4*(h1^2+h3^2)-9*qf^2)/(8*h1*h3)); 

Rot = RPYtoRot_ZXY(phif, thetaf, psif);
eps = [Rot*[2/3;0;0]+[xf;yf;zf]
   Rot*[2/3*h2*cos(alf1);2/3*h2*sin(alf1);0]+[xf;yf;zf]
   Rot*[2/3*h2*cos(alf2);-2/3*h3*sin(alf2);0]+[xf;yf;zf]];

 X  = [ xf yf zf phif thetaf psif pf qf betaf];

 Sf = [ 1; 2; pi/4];
 dSf = [0;0;0];

Pf = [ 0.1*t; 0; 0.5*sin(0.03*pi*t) + 2; 0; 0.01*pi*t ; 0];
dPf = [ 0.1; 0; 0.5*0.03*pi*cos(0.03*pi*t); 0; 0.01*pi; 0];

qd = [Pf; Sf];
qddot = [dPf; dSf];

jac = jacobian(eps,X);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
pf = Sf(1); qf = Sf(2); betaf = Sf(3);
xf = Pf(1); yf = Pf(2); zf = Pf(3);
phif = Pf(4); thetaf = Pf(5); psif = Pf(6);

x1=pos(1);
y1=pos(2);
z1=pos(3);
x2=pos(4);
y2=pos(5);
z2=pos(6);
x3=pos(7);
y3=pos(8);
z3=pos(9);

qpf=[(x1+x2+x3)/3;...
 (y1+y2+y3)/3;...
 (z1+z2+z3)/3;...
 atan2((2*z1/3-z2/3-z3/3),(2*y1/3-y2/3-y3/3)); ...
 -atan2((2*z1/3-z2/3-z3/3),(2*x1/3-x2/3-x3/3)); ...
 atan2((2*y1/3-y2/3-y3/3),(2*x1/3-x2/3-x3/3))];

 qsf=[sqrt((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2+(z1-z2)^2); ...
 sqrt((x1-x3)^2+(y1-y3)^2+(z1-z3)^2); ...
 acos((pf^2+qf^2-rf^2)/(2*pf*qf))];

 q = [qpf;qsf];
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%
 %%%pos_desired%%%%%%%
 pos_des =  eval(eps);
 pos_des =subs(pos_des,t,tm);
 jacval  =  eval(jac);

 qd = eval(qd);%subs(qd,t,tm);
 q  = eval(q);
 qe = qd - q;
 qddot = eval(qddot);%subs(qddot,t,tm);
 kappa=0.2*eye(9);
 qrefdot = qddot + kappa*qe;

 vel_des = jacval*qrefdot;
 vel_des = subs(vel_des,t,tm);
 acc_des = zeros(3,1);

 yaw = 0;
 yawdot = 0;
 % =================== Your code ends here ===================

 desired_state1 = [pos_des(1:3);vel_des(1:3);acc_des];
 desired_state2 = [pos_des(4:6);vel_des(4:6);acc_des];
 desired_state3 = [pos_des(7:9);vel_des(7:9);acc_des];
 Pf = subs(Pf,t,tm);
 Sf = subs(Sf,t,tm);
 format short
 digits(3);
 desired_state = vpa([desired_state1;desired_state2;desired_state3; psif; 0; 
 Pf; Sf])
 size(desired_state)
 end
```

Comment: Please post picture and upload your code to Stack Overflow. Don't expect people to download code from other sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second image shows that the output of the second function is a scalar - the dimension at the output of the block is 1 - not 38 as you believe it is.

That is, your functions *do not* give the same output as you believe they do.

The error is because the `Selector` blocks expect their inputs to be dimension 38, and they are not.

To determine why what you believe is happening is not actually what is happening, you could use the editor to set a break point in the m-code, run the model, then step through the code to determine why it gives a scalar output when you expect it to do otherwise.

Another approach would be to run your functions from the MATLAB Command Line with fake input data.  Something like

```
tmp = desiredtrajectory(randn(10,1))
```

would be appropriate here.

The answer is that `desiredtrajectory` outputs `desired_state`, which is a symbolic variable.  Yes it contains a 38 element vector, but Simulink treats the object itself is a scalar.

The real problem though is that you can't propagate a symbolic variable down a Simulink signal.  You need the output to be a numeric vector.

One way to overcome this is to put the line

```
desired_state = double(desired_state);
```

at the end of your file to cast the symbolic object to a double, which will have 38 elements.

(However it's not clear why you are using symbolic math in the first place, and I'd suggest it would be better, and is certainly more efficient, if you didn't use it.)